# Using the SMALL function: EXCEL

Tags: excel, function

If I use `=Small({VALUE(DV147),VALUE(DZ147),VALUE(ED147),VALUE(EH147)},2)` it does not work. But, if I use `SUM` and the `Value(-----)` amounts, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Note: The numbers are stored as text in those cells for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways:

```
=SMALL(VALUE(T(INDIRECT({"DV147","DZ147","ED147","EH147"}))),2)
```

or:

```
=SMALL(VALUE(T(OFFSET(DV147,,{0,4,8,12}))),2)
```

Comment: Thanks XOR LX, Ron for your help. Had to juggle to eliminate blank cells. This gave me the answer: =IF(DZ147="",SMALL(VALUE(T(OFFSET(DV147,,{0}))),1),IF(ED147="",SMALL(VALUE(T(OFFSET(DV147,,{0,4}))),1),IF(EH147="",SMALL(VALUE(T(OFFSET(DV147,,{0,4,8}))),1),SMALL(VALUE(T(OFFSET(DV147,,{0,4,8,12}))),1)))). I have to do a "LARGE" calculation with numerical inputs. Excel "runs out of memory" with this input: =IF(DT147="",0,IF(DX147="",LARGE(OFFSET(DT147,,{0}),1),IF(EB147="",LARGE(OFFSET(DT147,,{0,4}),1),IF(EG147="",LARGE(OFFSET(DT147,,{0,4,8}),1),LARGE(OFFSET(DT147,,{0,4,8,12}),1))))). Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question:

> What am I doing wrong?

The elements of an array constant need to be **constants**.  Formulas/Functions cannot be components of an array constant.  Although you can certainly use formulas to **create** an array, as shown by XOR LX in his answer.